# Circular progress bar around avatar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, progress-bar

I'm trying to figure out how to create a broken-dash progress bar around a profile image in Flutter, but am unsure how to proceed.

My original plan revolved around using borders, but I don't seem to be able to choose the *length* of a border. It always wraps around the entire widget, which is not what I want.

An example of what I'm looking for would be https://dribbble.com/shots/13974030-Longwalks-iOS-App-featured-by-Oprah-Winfrey

Ideally, I'd want the bar to be broken up into 5 or 10 "chunks" that each represent some percentage for at-a-glance visualization.

Which widgets should I be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider).

You can use it as a slider or a progress bar. Here's an example of how it would be used.

For it to be used as a progress bar just remove the `onChange` or `onChangeEnd`, this will remove the user's ability to interact with it.

```
  final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  initialValue: 426,
  onChange: (double value) {
    // callback providing a value while its being changed (with a pan gesture)
  },
  onChangeStart: (double startValue) {
    // callback providing a starting value (when a pan gesture starts)
  },
  onChangeEnd: (double endValue) {
    // ucallback providing an ending value (when a pan gesture ends)
  },
  innerWidget: (double value) {
    // use your custom widget inside the slider (gets a slider value from the callback)
  },
);
```

I'm not sure about dividing it into 'chunks' but it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

**dashed_circular_progress_bar: ^0.0.4**  pluggin used

```
SizedBox(
                height: 20,
                width: 20,
                child: DashedCircularProgressBar.aspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 2, // width ÷ height
                  progress: 25,
                  startAngle: 360,
                  sweepAngle: 360,
                  circleCenterAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffeeeeee),
                  foregroundStrokeWidth: 3,
                  backgroundStrokeWidth: 2,
                  backgroundGapSize: 2,
                  backgroundDashSize: 1,
                  //seekColor: Colors.yellow,
                  //seekSize: 22,
                  animation: true,
                  child:  SizedBox(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,8,12,3),
                        child: Icon(
                            Icons.play_arrow,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            size: 20
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```